# Redirect based on radio button choice

Tags: javascript, drupal, redirect

I am working on drupal platform.

I have created couple of surveys with drupal webforms.I have already redirection option in webform settings.
At the end of second webform there is a question with radio button.
When user submit the form it redirects automatically to 3th webform.

I would like to write a javascript code that if user checks "no" radio button then it redirects page (after user clicks submit button and the fields have to be saved before redirection) to last webform.

The button comes automatically by creation of webform. 
I couldnt find the div id of button.
When I click right and search elements, I get only this.

```
<input class="webform-submit button btn button-primary " name="op" value="Submit" type="submit">
```

Here is the code that I have tried

```
$("Button").click(function(){

   var value = document.getElementById("RadioButton_No"),
    if (value.checked) {
          window.location("https://www.com")
           }
}
```

Comment: What is `Button` and where is element `RadioButton_No`

Comment: I wrote there Button because I dont know how should I call button I dont have div id just div class I have.and here is element radiobutton no

<input required="required" class="radio" id="RadioButton_No" name="submitted[RadioButton_No]" value="2" type="radio">

Comment: Use `$('input[type=submit]')`. If there's more than one form on the page, try binding to the submit event of the enclosing form.